# Autofocus Bootstrap-Select on pageLoad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, focus

I am using Bootstrap-select. I would like to autofocus the first select in my form

```
<form id="myForm">
   <select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

I've tried adding the autofocus attribute in the HTML. I've also tried various ways of setting this on page load:

```
setTimeout('$("form select:first").focus()', 700);
setTimeout('$("#myForm select:first").focus()', 700);
setTimeout('$("#myForm #mySelect").focus()', 700);
```

I've confirmed the autofocus attribute is lost in the HTML generation using Bootstrap-select and the counter is working properly. How do I set the focus on load of a bootstrap-select?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="mySelect" class="selectpicker">
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Does the trick

Greetz

Comment: Unfortunately this was not a solution.

Comment: Why not? It's auto selecting the option you are using "selected" with.
Greetz

Comment: this doesn't not focus the selectpicker

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this focus using:

```
    $('#selector').on('show.bs.select', function (e) {
        $(this).find("bs-searchbox > input[type='text']:first").focus();
    });
```

The bs-searchbox is the div that wraps the textbox itself.

Comment: I had to use the event loaded.bs.select